# How to do swift slidedown error message like facebook app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, swift

I'm trying to show error message with slidedown animation view/label in iOS App (like "No Internet Connection" slidedown in facebook app)

What is the best way to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the Facebook app often enough to be familiar with what you are talking about, but simply animating a view/label down onto the screen is trivially easy with the UIView `animateWithDuration:animations:` family of methods.

If you're using Auto-Layout then you need to add a constraint to the vertical position of your label so that it's off the top of the screen, create an outlet to that constraint, and then change the constant value of the constraint and call layoutIfNeeded inside your animation block. It's pretty simple.